# iPhone sdk how to allow users to re-order tabbar items in IB built tabbar

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsuserdefaults, tabbar

I've been investigating this feature but it seems that most solutions require yo to have built your tababr programatically. My tab bar is built in IB and I don't particularly want to recode most of my app (unless I absolutely have to.)

For IB built tabbars I've not yet found a tutorial or guidance. Does anyone have a good link or a some information to help me?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabbar controller has a property named customizable view controllers. Views which are in this array are customizable through default edit button provided in more navigation controller of tabbar controller. So if your tabbar is having 5 or more view controllers in it, it will have more navigation controller at 5th tab. And that more navigation controller provides edit button to rearrange the tab bar items.

Comment: I do have more than five tab bar items and I'm aware of the Edit button. However, I do not know where to declare this customisable view controller property. Can you advise please - does it go in .h file?.

Comment: By default customizableViewController property holds all those view controllers which are in viewControllers property. If you want to modify it then create array of your desired view controllers and assign it to customizableViewControllers property.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have 5 or more tabs in the tabBar and you will get the "More" tab which allows reordering automatically.